# asp.net post xml to redirecting page

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, redirect, post

I posted an xml data from Desktop application to asp.net wep page. I can read xml at web page but if I redirect the page to another page, I get error at Desktop app. My codes are below. 
Thanks for help.

Desktop app:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        post();

        Console.WriteLine("Post process is successed...");
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void post() {
        System.Net.WebRequest req = null;
        System.Net.WebResponse rsp = null;
        try {
            req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:5318/Account/XMLReader.aspx");
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "text/xml";

            StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
            writer.WriteLine(getXmlData());
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();

            rsp = req.GetResponse();
        } catch {
            throw;
        } finally {
            if (req != null) req.GetRequestStream().Close(); // *****Error occures here****
            if (rsp != null) rsp.GetResponseStream().Close();
        }
    }
```

asp.net page code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        System.IO.StreamReader reader =
        new System.IO.StreamReader(Page.Request.InputStream);
        String xmlData = reader.ReadToEnd();

        Response.Redirect("/Account/Login.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: Please specify what error you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
private static void post()
        {
            System.Net.WebRequest req = null;
            System.Net.WebResponse rsp = null;
            Stream newStream = null;
            try
            {
                req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:39384/Default.aspx");
                req.Method = "POST";
                req.ContentType = "text/xml";

                newStream = req.GetRequestStream();
                StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(newStream);
                writer.WriteLine("ddd");
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();

                rsp = req.GetResponse();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (req != null) newStream.Close(); // *****Error occures here****
                if (rsp != null) rsp.GetResponseStream().Close();
            }
        }
```