# How to send data from a Sql Server to another Sql Server (Not Linked) Using C# ASP.NET HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to send data from one **Database (Server A)** to another **Database (Server B)**, on both server I have an ASP.NET application. I've searched about using a XML file with HttpClient Post. I don't want to use Web Service because i can't modify the Server B's application (I'll use an aspx file that already receive a xml from a Android App).

Any advice? If you can share some links about how can i do it i'll appreciate it :)

Thank you for your time, peace.

Comment: If you can't modify anything on Application B then you should probably try to create the xml and post it to the aspx page on Application B.How does the aspx file on Application B receive the xml from the Android App? Can't you use the same logic in your Application A to post it to Application B so that it handles the xml similar to the way it is handling the xml from the Android App? For posting xml data to the url see code sample here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096218/asp-net-post-xml-to-redirecting-page

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use an XML for transferring data. You can use a C# ADO.Net or Entity Framework console or windows program or ASP.net website (with a button control) that will have the functionality to collect the data from one server and insert it in the other server.

Comment: Yeah! I want to do your last advice, ASP.net website. But i don't know how to send it from one server to another server. That's the core of my question =) Thanks for answer !

Answer (score 0):

Can't you generate a `DataModel` for Server B's backend using `EntityFramework`?
If you can connect to Server B's database, you can generate this from Visual Studio.

Once you have your Conceptual Model, you can use `EntityFramework` to add data to the other server.

e.g.

```
using(var db = new ServerBDatabaseContext())
{
   db.databaseTable.Add(someObjectFromDatabaseA);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This video may help you accomplish what you're looking for
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff191186.aspx

Hope this helps.